# Transferring data between live python files

Tags: python

I have 11 python files that I run simultaneously, of which 10 generate data and 1 needs to receive some of the data from all 10 files.

file1.py (...) file10.py:

```
numbers = []

number = api(number)      #this number changes every so often due to an API call
numbers.append(number)
total_number = sum(numbers)
file11.all_data.append(total_number)
```

file11.py:

```
all_data = []
all_data_total = sum(all_data)

#and then goes on to use all_data_total to send it to telegram when a certain command is used in the telegram group chat, therefore the number needs to be updating in real time as soon as the API provides a new number in file 1-10.
```

I tried:

```
from file11 import all_data
```

And:

```
import file11
```

But neither worked. Because for some reason importing file11 gives me a TeleBot error (2021-04-20 23:19:04,473 (**init**.py:526 MainThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 409. Description: Conflict: terminated by other getUpdates request; make sure that only one bot instance is running") and to top it all off I have been informed that my idea of updating the list in file11 in real time will not work anyway, hence why I am now out of options and hope there is a solution out there for my problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look into concurrency/threading. Launching a threadpool with 10 workers would likely meet your requirements.

Comment: It sounds like your files 1 through 10 are maybe conflicting with each other by making a bunch of API calls at the same time?

Comment: @TeejayBruno could you elaborate a little bit further on that? I am still pretty new to python and am willing to learn.